# WordPress Acceso a Dashboard por IP en HTACCESS

Tags: wordpress

tengo un portal web insitucional en WordPress al cual le limité el acceso a Dashboard por IP utilizando lo siguente:

```
<FilesMatch "^(wp-login\.php)">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 10.X.X.A
Allow from 10.X.X.B
Allow from 10.X.X.C
Allow from 10.X.X.D
Allow from 10.X.X.E
Allow from 10.X.X.F
</FilesMatch>
```

Hasta alli todo bien, solo que ahora tengo un grupo de personas que necesitan acceder desde una VPN de otro proveedor que les asigna direcciones IP por DHCP por lo que necesito abrir para la subred 192.X.X.0/255 y he intentado lo siguiente:

```
 Allow from 192.X.X.0/255
```

Obtengo un 500 Internal Server Error

```
Allow from 192.X.X
```

También obtengo un 500 Internal Server Error

Alguna idea..???
Saludos Leo

Comment: Si quieres bloquear específicamente un archivo, puedes probar esto: `<Files "wp-login.php">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.0.0.0/255
</Files>` o poner tantos `Allow from` como direcciones quieres permitir. Nótese que aunque bloquees `wp-login`, se podría acceder por `wp-admin`, a no ser que controles el acceso por esa vía.

Comment: Si querés dar acceso a solo unos ips el orden debería estar al revés, primero Deny y luego Allow: Order Deny,Allow para que primero bloquee todo y luego hablilite las excepciones.

Comment: Tambien fijate como estas especificando el rango de direcciones. El número después de la barra indica la cantidad de 1s significativos de la máscara de red. /8 sería 255.0.0.0, /16 sería 255.255.0.0 por lo que /255 estaría erróneo.

Comment: O sea que si quiero especificar acceso para la subred 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255 y la máscara de subred es 255.255.255.0 el terminal sería 255...??? Algo como 192.168.1.0/255..??? hace ya 10 años que estudie direccionamiento y no recuerdo mucho.